# How to create a variable from a selected dropdown list and return it using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML page with a dropdown list, which represent specific time as follow:

```
  <div class="dropdown form-group col-xs-5" style="padding-right: 20px;">
        <label for="time">Temps</label>
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
   5 sec<span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" id="timeChoice">
            <li><a href="#" id="act1">5 sec</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="act2">10 sec</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="act3"> 15 sec</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="act4">30 sec</a></li>
        </ul>
 </div>
```

I want to create a function which identify the time and return a value assigned with this time. For instance when user click `sec5` the function put in the variable `timeOption = 5000;`
I use javascript and jQuery for that:

```
$('#act1').click(function(e) {
    var timeOption = 5000;
    alert(timeOption);
    e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor functionality
});
$('#act2').click(function(e) {
    var timeOption = 10000;
    alert(timeOption);
    e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor functionality
});
$('#act3').click(function(e) {
    var timeOption = 15000;
    alert(timeOption);
    e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor functionality
});
$('#act4').click(function(e) {
    var timeOption = 30000;
    alert(timeOption);
    e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor functionality
});
```

How to add a return statement with specific value ?

Comment: I don't understand your question at all :C

Comment: Please specify it more clearly.

Comment: @Kinduser I want for exmple when user click on `5 sec` or  `10 sec` a global ariable change its value dnamically and return it

Comment: Can I change your `html` code a little bit? I will shorten the javascript code then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code little bit. Add data attribute to every anchor tag and then write click handler

```js
$('#timeChoice').on("click", "a", function(e) {
    var timeOption = e.target.getAttribute('data-time')*1000;
    alert(timeOption);
    e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor functionality
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown form-group col-xs-5" style="padding-right: 20px;">
        <label for="time">Temps</label>
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
   5 sec<span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" id="timeChoice">
            <li><a href="#" id="act1" data-time="5">5 sec</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="act2"  data-time="10">10 sec</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="act3"  data-time="15"> 15 sec</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="act4"  data-time="30">30 sec</a></li>
        </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a return statement, but that is not the right approach, because an event callback isn't called from a context where you can handle the function's return value (the return value ends up in a jQuery function and gets handled there). You want to make your timeOption value visible to some other function, which you can do in various ways. In this case, I would suggest passing the value to a function:

```
$('#act1').click(function(e) {
    var timeOption = 5000;
    alert(timeOption);
    e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor functionality

    handleTimeOption(timeOption);
});

$('#act2').click(function(e) {
    var timeOption = 10000;
    alert(timeOption);
    e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor functionality

    handleTimeOption(timeOption);
});    
$('#act3').click(function(e) {
    var timeOption = 15000;
    alert(timeOption);
    e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor functionality

    handleTimeOption(timeOption);
});
$('#act4').click(function(e) {
    var timeOption = 30000;
    alert(timeOption);
    e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor functionality

    handleTimeOption(timeOption);
});

function handleTimeOption(timeOption) {
    // Here goes whatever code you want to run when a time option has been selectedl
}
```

Comment: Thank you but in the case of my code, I have 4 options, I want that at each click the correspondant option treated well

Comment: This is an example - you can add the same call to all four functions.

Comment: @HaKiM's Just to clarify, since it was unclear to you, I've added the other three functions with the same call. To be clear, I've intentionally written this to be as close to your original code as possible - Pankaj's solution is much better code and you should try to learn to write handlers like that.